# Emacs orgmode always display inline image at startup

Tags: org-mode, images

Somehow my Emacs always displays inline images by default, which is not what I want. I've tried the following but none of them worked:

1. Add `#+STARTUP: noinlineimages` at the top of a file.
2. Explicitly set `org-startup-with-inline-images` to nil, although it is nil by default.
3. To rule out the possibility of a local variable somewhere, I created a file in /tmp/ and open it in Emacs. Still displaying inline image.

`org-toggle-inline-images` does work, but I want Emacs to stop displaying inline image at startup.

Emacs version: GNU Emacs 28.1 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0, Carbon Version 164 AppKit 2022.6) of 2022-04-09

Comment: After starting up when images are visible, evaluate the relevant variable to see whether it is indeed `nil`.  You can use `C-h v` or `M-x eval-expression` and type in the name of the variable.  If the variable is non-nil, then something in your settings may be setting it afterwards.

Comment: I'm also running 28.1, just ran `emacs -q` and this is the behaviour I get (in-line images do not display by default). I suspect the culprit may be somewhere in your init.el.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: @lawlist It's nil. "Local in buffer .... Global value is the same."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, it's because of the use of `org-inline-pdf` package, which executes `(org-display-inline-images)` every time you turn on `org-inline-pdf-mode`, and I have this mode bind to orgmode. My solution is to remove that line of code in `org-inline-pdf.el`.